# Magento Staging Websites and Redis cache invalidation

Tags: caching, magento, redis

This is on a multi-store solution.

I am testing out the Redis caching system, explained in detail by Vinai Kopp on this link: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/improving-the-file-cache-backend/

I am testing to see, if I edit a product in a Staging Website C (staging copy of Website A), that it will invalidate the product page in the original website A.

When I checked it, the product in Website B was fine and the page seems to stay cached.

When I edited the product under the Store View of Website C (copy of Website A), and refreshed the "product display page" in Website A, it seemed that the page data was invalidated, and the cache was cleaned and recreated.

Is this expected behavior, or is this a bug with Redis?

Which tools can I use, besides xdebug stepping through the Redis.php code, to test the caching of these tags?

More help would be appreciated, and some light on the topic on Staging Websites and caching would help too.

**Further Investigation:**
The ID the got saved again, is called "06d_CUSTOM_MODULE_BLOCK_MAINMENU_STORE_2"
And the tags are:

```
06d_CATALOG_PRODUCT
06d_BLOCK_HTML
06d_MAGE
```

Make any sense?

Does not really look like the Product page content is being refreshed, but the menu is?

I am a bit confused with this one.

The following code creates this tag in our MainMenu.php block:

```
/**
 * Make the block cacheable
 */
protected function _construct()
{
 $this->addData(array(
   'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
   'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG), //delete this cache on change of any product
   'cache_key'      => 'Custom_Module_Block_Mainmenu_store_'. Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),  //static cache key cos this block is the same on every page
 ));
}
```

I really think this has something to do with whichever website is set as the default, will get refreshed / re-cached.

Comment: I generally like logging the cache id's and tags that get deleted to see what's happening with caching, like it seems you did, too. From what you posted I would say cache records from product page are not cleared from the cache. The menu block is deleted because of the cache tag. I'm interested to read what your research will come to.

Comment: @Vinai, I will update the details, when I have done more testing. Was hoping someone else came across this. And also the Staging Website update should not interfere with the live one at all!

Comment: If you add the store ID (or website ID) to the cache key of the menu block that would be the case. Magento simply does what it's told to do (not an easy task sometimes).

Comment: When I update the product in the Staging website ID7, then refresh the Product page under normal website ID2, the "06d_CUSTOM_MODULE_BLOCK_MAINMENU_STORE_2" tag gets recreated. What that has to do with store 7, I have no idea.

Comment: It probably is the cache tag Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG. Thats probably why the cache record is deleted regardless of the store id in the key. (Haven't tried, but it would make sense). It tells Magento to refresh the record once any product is edited.

Comment: the funny bit is, when I refresh Store ID 3, on the same product, this does not happen. Maybe when you put a specific website into Stage Website mode, it has some sort of back link to the original copy of it. The http made no difference, by the way.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to dig into the code. The truth is in there somewhere =)

Comment: Makes sense to invalidate cache in all websites when you update a product, because some product attributes are global (not website or store view specific), therefore if you change them in a website that information is changed in all of them. As a result: cache should be invalidated in all websites.